# Attention transformation - matrices

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, matrix, softmax

Could somebody explain which matrix dimension should be found here - K? and if it is for example 3X3, should I use just 9?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d_k$ is the dimensionality of the query/key/value vectors. In your example, the length of those vectors is 3, so $d_k = 3$

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Noe's answer, you could consider $d_k$ being the equivalent of`hidden_state` dimensionality as seen in recurrent layers e.g. argument `units` in `tf.keras.layers.LSTM`.